# Trouble using C++11 lambda function to connect a click event to a function

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda

In a GUI application, I have quite a few pushbuttons that are being used. These pushbuttons are labelled as `pbxx` where `xx` is the row and column number of the pushbutton in a grid layout. When a pushbutton is pressed, it needs to be highlighted. Today I read about lambda functions [Brian Poteat](http://artandlogic.com/2013/09/qt-5-and-c11-lambdas-are-your-friend/) & [Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182670/qt-how-to-know-that-a-pushbutton-is-clicked) and thought I would try to implement this in my code.

In my GuiDisplay class (a class that inherits QMainWindow), I have a function called:

```
make_connections();
```

which would make all my pushbutton connections (all signals are connected to a single slot `on_pushbutton_clicked()`.  I added the code here:

### The GuiDisplay Class

```
class GuiDisplay : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GuiDisplay(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GuiDisplay();

    ... Some more public functions ...

    /**
     * @brief Connects all custom signals and slots.
     */
    void make_connections();

    /**
     * @brief Will highlight the provided pushbutton with provided rgb colour
     */
    void highlight_pushbutton(QPushButton &pb, const int rgb[]);

private slots:
    void on_pushbutton_clicked(const QString& label);

private:
    Ui::GuiDisplay *ui;
};
```

### The make_connections function of the GuiDisplay Class

```
void GuiDisplay::make_connections()
{
    // Loop through all the pushbuttons and connect clicked signal to clicked slot
    QString pb_label = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            // Find the pushbutton
            pb_label = "pb" + QString::number(i) + QString::number(j);
            QPushButton* pb_ptr = this->findChild<QPushButton*>(pb_label);
            //connect(pb_ptr, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushbutton_clicked()));
            connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label);});
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes up when I make the connection

```
connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label);});
```

the build gives me the following error

```
'pb_label' is not captured
```

so I thought ok, well then it wouldn't seem wrong to do the following instead:

```
connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, &pb_label]{on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label);});
```

The error at build time fell away, however my GUI application unexpectedly crashes whenever this code is executed. Not sure why. Any help here?

Comment: Capture `pb_label` by value, i.e., `[this, pb_label]`

Comment: Or you can use `[=]`

Answer (score 4):

Your error is due to using a reference to a temporary. `pb_label` only exists for the duration of `GuiDisplay::make_connections` your lambda is stored by Qt and will be referenced each time the signal is fired. When that happens you'll reference a destroyed object.

So the correct way to make the connection is:

```
connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]{ on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label); });
```

As of Qt 5.2 the [`QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *context, Functor functor, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5) overload was added which will automatically disconnect at the end of an object's lifetime. In this case the connection would be:

```
connect(pb_str, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]{ on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label); });
```

---

That said you shouldn't use a lambda here when you could simply do:

```
connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &GuiDisplay::on_pushbutton_clicked);
```

Then modify your `GuiDisplay::on_pushbutton_clicked` to take no arguments. You can obtain the name of the object in `GuiDisplay::on_pushbutton_clicked` by calling: [`sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) which will:

> Returns a pointer to the object that sent the signal

Then just use [`QObject::objectName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) to get `pb_label`:

> This property holds the name of this object

So, you'll just need to replace `pb_label` with: `sender()->objectName()`

There are several reasons why the direct slot connection is preferable to a lambda:

1. It removes the need to store a temporary lambda *and* a temporary `QString` for `pb_label`
2. It removes the lambda indirection that requires an additional stack frame
3. Debugging into lambdas is not always developer friendly, though some IDEs mitigate this problem
4. [Prior to Qt 5.2 there was no way to disconnect a lambda slot if objects it depended upon were destroyed](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Connecting_in_Qt5):

> There is no automatic disconnection when the 'receiver' is destroyed because it's a functor with no `QObject`.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning, that assuming Qt 5.2 or newer is used, if you need automatic disconnection when some object is destroyed, you can pass that object as the [`context object`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5).

Comment: @thuga Fair point, I actually even censored that from my quote of the Qt wiki. I never bothered to upgrade from Qt 5.1 and I was working under the non-sense mindset that no one is using Qt 5.2. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Piotr Skotnicki and Simple, both of your suggestions work. I probably should have read a bit further and I would have seen [=] in the capture-list (See: [Lambda](http://Thank%20you%20@PiotrSkotnicki,%20both%20of%20your%20suggestions%20work.%20I%20probably%20should%20have%20read%20a%20bit%20further%20and%20I%20would%20have%20seen%20[=]%20(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)))

So, my one line of code that causes the problem can be either:

```
connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, pb_label]{on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label);});
```

or

```
connect(pb_ptr, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]{on_pushbutton_clicked(pb_label);});
```

Comment: FWIW, when it's captured by reference, `[this, &pb_label]`, then the original object (that the captured reference points to) is destroyed on an exit from `make_connections`, that's why you encounter crashes